# Schema Merging not working when the s3 paths are given explicitly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

When the s3 paths is explicitly given to read parquet files that are not in the same directory, the partitioning schemes aren't inferred and hence i dont get the partitioned column in my spark dataframe.

I have tried the option merge schema = True while reading the parquet files but that seems to work when given the root folder and not explicit paths.

My Current s3 directory structure.

```
bucket
    folder1
        .....|- col=val1/file1.parquet
        .....|- col=val2/file2.parquet
        .....|- col=val3/file3.parquet
        .....
    folder2
        .....|- col=val1/file4.parquet
        .....|- col=val2/file5.parquet
        .....|- col=val3/file6.parquet
        .....
    .....
```

I want to read all the files that has the value val1 and val2 for the key col.
Hence, i get the s3 paths of those as a list and read them explicitly.

```py
s3paths = ['s3://bucket/folder1/col=val1/file1.parquet',
's3://bucket/folder1/col=val2/file2.parquet',
's3://bucket/folder1/col=val1/file4.parquet',
's3://bucket/folder2/col=val2/file5.parquet']

df = spark.read.parquet(*s3paths) 

# another option
df = spark.read.options("mergeSchema", True).parquet(*s3paths)
```

I am able to read the files but the column col doesn't appear in the spark dataframe.

I expect the colum 'col' to be present in my dataframe.

Comment: Once you partition data by a particular column in writing it out to storage, that column is exempted from data. you can still filter on the column if you read the parent directory. Do you need the column for anything other than filtering?

Comment: I want to do aggregation on those files. I have to use group by on the partitioned column so that i aggregate for each partition. The number of files are too many to read them all at once. (230000 files - 1.2Tb).

Comment: Then you can use pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name() (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name) to get the directory for parquet file and write a regular expression to extract the values of column of interest from it.

Comment: I can add this as a column in my dataframe using withColumn? The only doubt i have is , an individual spark task can process multiple files ,right ? If so,which file name does it return ?

Comment: Correct, you can use withColumn. The transformation will return the directory of the file that holds the record for each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the folder structure of my data.
    data
        .....|- period_id=201909/file1.csv
        .....|- period_id=201910/file2.csv
file1.csv
---------
Name,Age
Amit,28
Ashish,30
Swaraj,27

file2.csv
----------
Name,Age,Sal
Amit,28,10000
Ashish,30,20000
Swaraj,27,15000

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()


current_period = "201910"
prev_period = "201909"
mergedDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("mergeSchema", "true").option("header", "true")\
    .option("inferSchema", "true")\
    .load(["data/period_id={current_period}/*".format(current_period=current_period),
           "data/period_id={prev_period}/*".format(prev_period=prev_period)]) \
    .withColumn("filename", input_file_name())

splitDF = mergedDF.withColumn("period_with_file_name", F.split(F.col("filename"), "=").getItem(1))\
    .withColumn("period_date_yyyymm",F.split(F.col("period_with_file_name"), "/").getItem(0).astype("int"))\
    .drop("filename", "period_with_file_name")

splitDF.printSchema()

splitDF.show(truncate=False)

Output
----------
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sal: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- period_date_yyyymm: integer (nullable = true)

+------+---+-----+------------------+
|Name  |Age|Sal  |period_date_yyyymm|
+------+---+-----+------------------+
|Amit  |28 |10000|201910            |
|Ashish|30 |20000|201910            |
|Swaraj|27 |15000|201910            |
|Amit  |28 |null |201909            |
|Ashish|30 |null |201909            |
|Swaraj|27 |null |201909            |
+------+---+-----+------------------+

The column 'col' i.e 201910, 201909 here is present in the dataframe.

This code is as per my case. Just change based on your requirement.
```